# Printing a specific value of a Hash?

Tags: hash

I want to print (or return at some point), the user input that is located in a hash using ids.

```
puts "Introduzca su usuario"
user_name = gets.chomp
puts "Ahora su contraseña"
user_password = gets.chomp
puts "Un recordatorio de su contraseña"
user_reminder = gets.chomp

data = {
    user: user_name,
    password: user_password,
    reminder: user_reminder
}

data.each {|form, value| 
    puts "Your information is #{value}"
}
```

Using this I can print every user's input, but what if I want to print just the first, the second or the third?

EDIT

I know I can print directly the user_name, user_password and user_reminder variables, but I want to retrieve a value from the hash itself